Bastions or Strongholds?
Hi recently asked a few questions about the new Bastions mechanic in D&D 5e. These were tagged with bastions, and now have been re-edited to strongholds, which is a tag for this concept of a home base for the party in general.
My questions were pretty specific to the detailed mechanics of bastions, not so much about how to handle strongholds in general. I'd be happy to use either tag, and maybe use bastions as an alias for strongholds, but I thought it might be useful to ask for input here if we should have those as two separate tags, or just one tag with maybe alias, and why either solution would be better.

Do the two things really differ? Or can they all just be synonyms for "home base" or similar concept?

If Bastions are a specific mechanic (Bastion is a capitalized keyword in 5e-2024 AFAIK), doesn't it make sense for it to have its own tag?

Why not both?
I'd like to make a case here for what I've (at least to myself) been calling double-barrel tags, ie. tags of the form "X-and-Y". Specifically this would be strongholds-and-bastions
The main argument is that our tags are supposed to be for concepts and opposed to terms, though tags are usually named for the first and/or dominant term for that concept. In many cases that causes no issues, but in this one it certainly looks like we're headed into the realm of having two strong terms for exactly the same concept.
Having the tag be a combination of the two would mean users of either concept naturally find it and is make it read well as referring to the general concept as opposed to any one implementation of it.
Previous examples of this style of tag-naming would be followers-and-hirelings, vision-and-light, and religion-and-deities.

FWIW, I'd prefer tags to be a little bit less product-specific if they are to encompass a wider concept. Religion and deities can apply to basically any setting. Ditto for vision and light. Followers and hirelings are a bit more specific terms but still understandable. But "strongholds and bastions" as a stand-in for "player base" (or "home base") is just too specific. Presumably I can use it for a "base" in a modern setting. The base being an apartment. But doesn't feel right. And yes, I'm acutely aware my views on tag specificity/generality are mostly not shared with the site.

also: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicine-and-drugs

@VLAZ base-of-operations maybe, as opposed to player-base (which would be about the people playing a game)

Alternatively, it'd also be possible to just have one term be the primary name of the tag, and add the other as a synonym of that tag. ("Strongholds" seems appropriately generic as a name, while "bastions" feels a bit more specific – I haven't seen it used in TTRPGs for this concept outside of D&D.)

I don't think there's much call to make this non-product-specific right now. Our reference points are exactly two games: D&D and a game that's deliberately recreating the experience of D&D. Bastions or Strongholds works just fine there. There's no demonstrated need to cover other games yet, and we might accidentally export a D&D-ism where it's not appropriate for other games. Once we get questions about this stuff emerging from other games, we can then make a call about how to address that situation (if it needs any changes) based on actual concrete data on site.
